# Why isn't Gradle adding the SQLite JAR files to my Java project?

Tags: java, sqlite, gradle, build.gradle

First of all, I'm pretty new to Gradle. My problem is that Gradle isn't adding the SQLite JAR files to my project even though I included them in my build.gradle file and the project was built correctly.

I followed the following tutorial in order to build my Java project with Gradle:
[Building Java Applications Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_applications.html)
Then I added the following code to my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.toedter:jcalendar:1.4'
    implementation group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.40.0.0'
}

testing {
    suites {
        // Configure the built-in test suite
        test {
            // Use JUnit Jupiter test framework
            useJUnitJupiter('5.9.1')
        }
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'myApp.App'
}
```

Notice that I've also used the JCalendar library, which works just fine.
Despite being able to build the project succesfully and using the JCalendar library, when I check if the SQLite library is available I can't find nor use it. Also, when I execute the following code:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    }
```

I get the following error:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC`
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run "gradle clean build" command in gradle file directory?

Comment: Yes, I did, and then I rebuilt the project.

Comment: There might be conflicting dependencies. Check gradle dependency tree to see if you dependency is overwritten

Comment: how do you run the main ? via gradle or by command line or some custom script ? `gradle run` seems to work ok for me

Comment: @GökhanPolat I don't know how to do that, could you provide me with a link please?

Comment: @PrasadU I ran it both ways and it still didn't import the libraries.